# 4NEC2 shortening factor "x"

Tags: antenna-modeling

I read on pg5 of Antenna Simulation with 4NEC2 about **shortening factor "x"**.
It is very specific and I can't figure out how to use it in a general nec file.
It sounds like SY x=0.907 in the nec file will shorten all the Y parameters, but that doesn't make sense to this newbee.
I would think it would reduce the larger dimension (end) to yield the 0.907 reduction. Maybe it does. I tried it on my file with no apparent result. IE, the plots did not change to reflect a different resonant frequency.
Anyplace I can find a better explanation of this feature?
thanks

Comment: Please add a link to "Antenna Simulation with 4NEC2".

Comment: Found it: [Antenna simulations with 4NEC2 including an application example for 2300MHz](http://www.vhfcomm.co.uk4nec2%20antenna%20simulation%20english.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is on page 6 of [Antenna simulations with 4NEC2 including an application example for 2300MHz](http://www.vhfcomm.co.uk4nec2%20antenna%20simulation%20english.pdf):

[image]

A symbol (SY), x, is defined as having the value 0.907. This value is used in the calculations for the lengths of the dipole arms in the following GW statement.

I prefer doing this with the Symbols tab in 4NEC2's "NEC Editor (new)" (see Settings). The defined symbols are used in entries on the Geometry tab to define wire endpoints and other values.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I saw that and I did add that SY to my file but I got no result from it. I assumed I did not need the other 3 SYs and therefore the boxed item are also not relevant, but I have no clue. I am trying figure out if I can reduce the BW of my unit and get more gain. Though I have not figured out how to model my narods since they have an S curve in them. I might be easier to reform them to top hats.

Comment: @ruggb adding a symbol doesn't do anything unless you *use* it by referring to it in the geometry.